# Conjugacy in a normalizer of a Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I am trying to solve problem No. 9.7 of Isaacs "Algebra: A Graduate Course", which says:

For a Sylow p-subgroup $P$ of $G$ and $M, N \unlhd P$, if $M $ and $N$ are conjugate in $G$ then they are conjugate in $N_G(P)$?

It does not seem a difficult problem, but I have no clue how to start. Can someone give the clue! Thanks!

Comment: @Dune Uh I am so sorry! Yes! I will correct it.

Comment: Hint: $P$ is a Sylow subgroup of both $N_G(M)$ and $N_G(N)$.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks! Can you please write me down whole proof?

Comment: No. Feel free to post an answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in general if $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$, with $H \subseteq N_G(K)$, then $H^g \subseteq N_G(K^g)$ for any $g \in G$.

Now, assume $M^g=N$ for some $g \in G$. Since $M \unlhd P$, we have $P \subseteq N_G(M)$. Hence, by the previous remark, $P^g \subseteq N_G(M^g)=N_G(N)$. Since $N \unlhd P$, we have $P \subseteq N_G(N)$. Now apply Sylow theory in $N_G(N)$ (both $P$ and $P^g$ are here Sylow subgroups), there must be an $x \in N_G(N)$, such that $P^x=P^g$. This implies $gx^{-1} \in N_G(P)$. Finally $M^{gx^{-1}}=N^{x^{-1}}=N$, where the last equality holds because $x \in N_G(N)$.

Comment: Thanks! Very elegant proof!